# Symfony - Assign an internal FORM function to a Button of this FORM

Tags: php, forms, symfony, button, event-handling

I want to set the Month and the Year (they are a ChoiseType Fields), with some preimpostated values, by the click of a button *(*button: `'current_date'`*, see the code below)*.

This button is inside the same form of the choise fields (month and year).

I don't want to handle this action from the controller, but **! I WANT THAT IS ALL DONE INTERNALLY TO THIS FormType !** :-)

I know that I can achieve the result by using javascript, but it's not what I want and it's not what I need, beacuse if move this FormType File in another project I don't want to write something (like javascript) in another file.

Possible options that I thought, but I don't know if they are realizable:

- give a function to the `current_date` ButtonType *(add under the* `'lable'` *row, see the code below)*
- create an handler/listener function inside this `FormType` *(add under the function* `getYears()`*, see the code below)*

FormType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use ...

class LicenseSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',null,[
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('filter', CheckboxType::class,[
                'label' => 'Use filter ?',
                'mapped' => false,  // means that this checkbox in not related with the entity
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('month', ChoiceType::class,[
                'choices' => $this->getMonths(),
                'data' => date('n'),            // set the current month
            ])
            ->add('year', ChoiceType::class,[
                'choices' => $this->getYears(2000),
                'data' => date('Y'),            // set the current Year
            ])
            ->add('current_date', ButtonType::class,[
                'label' => 'current date',
                // -------------------------------------------
                // ------------  add something here   --------
                // -------------------------------------------
            ])
        ;
    }

    protected function getMonths(){...}

    protected function getYears($min, $max='current'){...}

    // -------------------------------------------
    // ---- or ----  add something here   --------
    // -------------------------------------------

    // public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){...}
    
}
```

the rendering of this Form:

[image: the rendering of this Form]

Comment: This sounds like a job for Javascript, if I understood your intentions correctly.

Comment: If you are setting the initial values to the current date, then wouldn't this button do the same as a `<input type="reset">`?

Comment: `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ResetType::class`

Comment: @El_Vanja Yeah It's true, I kwno how to do that, but it's something externalt at the form and if I decide to take this file a use it in an another project I don't want to go and create again a javascript code to do that. Thanks for the help anyway :-)

Comment: @ArleighHix Yeah it's works if i want to reset everything. BUT for example if I want to use some custom parameters (month and year) that they are different from the default ones I can't do that. And when I click the reset button ('current_date', in the code) it's also going to clear what I wrote in the search bar, and It's not what I want. Thanks anyway for the help :-)